# Help! kernel_task / Mac OS System eating hard drive space

Tags: hard-drive, partition, ssd

I have a very unfortunate problem. My Mac OS System is eating free disk space right before my eyes till my system becomes unresponsive.

I already deactivated and deleted Time Machine backups.

Finder says I have 100 GB of free space, but I constantly get (running low on disc space error). and Clean my Mac is reporting that I only have 8 MB of free space.

I checked the Disc Utility and my SSD is showing 100 GB of free space and (100 GB of purgeable), but it's nested inside another drive called "Container Disk1" and this one has only 8mb of free space (which is again nested in APPLE SSD SM1024F Media).

I tried first ad on Container Disk1 and it shows the following error "warning: Overallocation Detected on Main device"

I checked with DaisyDisk and it's reporting that there is 100GB of purgeable space, I tried to delete it, but it fails.

I manually deleted everything from Library/Cache/ to no avail.

Activity Monitor says that kernel_task wrote a massiv 185 GB to the HDD :(

it seams like every free mb is being written to some undeleteable area or the free space has not really been deleted.

How to I fix this? Help

Edit: Mac OS says my System is 600GB big, seems very wrong!

Comment: There are some basic mis-conceptions going on here. Container Disk1 is the overall container for your APFS volumes. Any volumes within that will automatically resize as & when needed; the data capacity is shared between all volumes in the container. You can't 'delete' purgeable; it will delete itself as & when needed, or pop a dialog asking you how you wish to manage storage.

Comment: well it isn't deleting itself...